# How to sort only odd rows (and keep even rows after corresponding odd rows) using jquery?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have table with odd rows with basic info and even rows with some content:

```
Title  Category  AnotherColumn

Title1 Category1 AnotherColumn1
Content1
Title2 Category2 AnotherColumn2
Content2
Title3 Category3 AnotherColumn3
Content3
Title4 Category4 AnotherColumn4
Content4
```

Using javascript to show/hide content rows, but now I have added sorting using jQuery like this (using tutorial from http://tablesorter.com/docs/):

table:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
 <thead>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th> Category</th>
  <th>AnotherColumn</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 {foreach over data, filling table}
  <tr class="odd">
   <td onclick="showContent($id)">$titles</td>
   <td>$categories</td> 
   <td>$anothercolumns</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="$id" class="even" style="display: none;">
   <td colspan="3">$contents</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#myTable").tablesorter();
);
```

But result of this that all rows get sorted, so when i show content, lets say of Title2, it looks like this:

```
Title1 Category1 AnotherColumn1
Title2 Category2 AnotherColumn2
Title3 Category3 AnotherColumn3
Title4 Category4 AnotherColumn4
Content2
```

Is there a way to solve this? Or do you have another idea how to insert content like that?
Thanks for help.

Comment: I think you want http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm

Comment: I was aiming for something like this, thanks.

Comment: Actually, it seems that the plugin I linked to has been incorporated into tablesorter 2.0.5, the docs just haven't been updated. You should be able to use the cssChildRow option without the plugin.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino You're correct. I actually have a [blog post](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html) with the missing tablesorter documentation.